# django-bootstrap-v5 DecimalField Throwing Errors in ModelForm Class

Tags: django, bootstrap-5

Using the django-bootstrap-v5 module, I get the error:

"**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'"

on a DecimalField Widget in the definition of a ModelForm class for a simple Model.  The Model is defined as follows:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    menuname=models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    description=models.TextField()
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
```

And the Model Form is defined as follows:

```
class MenuItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MenuItem
        fields='__all__'
        widgets = {'menuname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'price': forms.DecimalField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                }
```

The error is thrown on the Line:

```
'price': forms.DecimalField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
```

If I change that line to:

```
'price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
```

Then no error it thrown.  But of course I would rather use a DecimalField widget rather than a TextInput to render the underlying DecimalField in the model.

Once again this is using the django-bootstrap-v5 module.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forms.DecimalField` is a form **field** not a **widget**. The default widget used by `DecimalField` is [`NumberInput` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) hence you should use that instead:

```
class MenuItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'menuname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Your answer was correct and solved the problem.